# Integrate by Partial Fractions or Substitution

Tags: calculus

Evaluate 
$$\int\frac{e^xdx}{(e^{2x}-1)(e^x+1)}$$

I tried to decompose the integrand into A and B partial fractions.  No success.

Comment: Partial fractions is only an option when the denominator is the product of polynomials. You have exponential functions at the moment.

Comment: Note that you can think of this as $\int \frac{du}{(u^2-1)(u+1)}$ by taking $u=e^x$

Comment: @EthanHunt These are polynomials in $e^x$.  Partial fraction decomposition is certainly possible here.  Though it would probably be easier to do $u=e^x$ sub first.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  For a first step, let $u=e^x$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. After the substitution $t=e^x$ (remember that $e^x dx=dt$), it remains to integrate
$$\int\frac{dt}{(t^2-1)(t+1)}=\int\frac{dt}{(t+1)^2(t-1)}=A\int \frac{dt}{t+1}+B\int \frac{dt}{(t+1)^2}+C\int \frac{dt}{t-1}$$
for some real constants $A,B,C$.

P.S. $A=-1/4$, $B=-1/2$, and $C=1/4$, therefore
$$\int\frac{e^x\; dx}{(e^{2x}-1)(e^x+1)}=
\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{|e^x-1|}{e^x+1}\right)+
\frac{1}{2(e^x+1)}+const.
$$

Comment: So, ah-ha moment for me.  I thought I could decompose into A/(t+1)^2 + B/(t-1).

Comment: @Mike If you have a factor $(t-a)^n$ at the denominator you have to include $1/(t-a)^k$ for $k=1,..,n$ in the decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

like above we have $$\int \frac{1}{(t^2-1)(t+1)}dt$$ after partail frac decombistion we get $$1/2\, \left( t+1 \right) ^{-1}-1/4\,\ln  \left( t+1 \right) +1/4\,\ln 
 \left( t-1 \right) 
$$