# Can't solve integral by partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

Seems this should work via partial fractions; however, doesn't solve out for me.
I recoginize that $e^{2x}-1$ is a difference of squares. Still doesn't decompose for me with partial fractions.

numerator is $e^x$

demominotor is $(e^{2x}-1)(e^x+1)$

$$\int \frac{e^x}{(e^2x-1)  (e^x+1)}dx$$

Comment: There is an identical question posted recently (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954969/integrate-by-partial-fractions-or-substitution). Is it a kind of homework?

Comment: put $u=e^x$ and decompose in partial fractions.

Comment: do you mean $$\int \frac{e^x}{(e^{2x}-1)(e^{x}+1)}dx$$?

Comment: Sorry on duplication.  I was trying to close one account and it entered anyway on both accounts.

Comment: Yes, that is the integral.  No, it is not homework, but a quiz problem that I couldn't get correct and instructor simply said do it by partial fractions.  "Do it by partial fractions" doesn't help much if you get stuck.

Comment: Nice find, @Daniel